# Edit value in DataRowView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm using VS 2008 at the moment for my development (ASP.NET C#).

Currently I'm facing some problem with GridView:

I bind data to the GridView DataSource using a DataSet (query from database), I then have a checkbox which allow user to hide or display the column using the following method :

```
    if (chkPhone.Checked == true) { strSQL += ", recruit_website as 'Website'"; }
```

Okay now the problem I facing is that, how do I make this specific column rows to wrap with anchor tag? So that user can go to the respective website directly though the GridView.

So the first approach I use was to use the 'RowDataBound' event and do something like :

```
    e.Row.Cells[7].Text = "<a href='" + e.Row.Cells[7].Text + '">Click Me</a>";
```

But then the problem comes, IF the user choose not to display this column, the column index will be different. (There are more options for user to hide the column so -1 in index doesn't make sense)

Well so this approach fails, I tried using another approach which is using the DataRowView in the 'RowDataBound' event :

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        rowView["Website"] = "something"; //something to deal with here
    }
```

Using this method I can get the value from the GridView using the column name, but I can't set the value.

So what's the best solution for this situation?

Comment: I got a suggestion: You should probably change the value of that column BEFORE you databind. That way you do not have to worry about the users selection of visible columns. Hope it helps

Comment: @Koen Yes I had tried that by using CONCAT while fetching the data from MS SQL, but then when displaying in the Gridview, it's not encode as HTML, if you know how to encode a specific column to html then this problem is resolved :) Thanks for suggesting though!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to check on which columns you want to do it, but i think this might help

```
 // Your code for filling dataset
foreach(dataTable theTable in dataSet.Tables)
    {
           foreach(DataRow row in theTable.Rows)
            {
                foreach(DataColumn cell in theTable.Columns)
                {
                    string value = row[cell].ToString();
                    row[cell] = "<a href='" + value + "'>" + value + "</a>";

                }
            }
    }
//Your databinding and stuff;
```

This might work too:

```
foreach(dataTable theTable in dataSet.Tables)
        {
               foreach(DataRow row in theTable.Rows)
                {
                    foreach(DataColumn cell in theTable.Columns)
                    {
                       string value = row[cell].ToString();
                      HyperLink linker = new HyperLink();
                       DataColumn col = new DataColumn();

                     linker.NavigateUrl = value; // you need to change this so it works
                     col.DefaultValue = linker;

                      row[cell] = col;

                    }
                }
        }
```

Final guess: This is not optimal, but it worked for me. You need to do this before the user can do anything but after the databind.

```
 foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
          {
              foreach(TableCell cell in row.Cells)
              {
                  string value = col.Text.toString();
                  col.Text = "<a href='" + value + "'>" + value + "</a>";
              }
          }
```

Comment: Hi I had tried to do something with this loop and the result is the same that I use CONCAT, the data are display exactly as it look like in html instead of encode to become a link :(

Comment: Okay i will add another solution that might do the trick, Not sure if it works but you can always try and let me know what happened

Comment: Hi I had tried your solution but I not sure what to change for the comment line you refer? Anyway by setting row[cell] = link; it give me `System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink` for the whole column.

Comment: @MiloJuakMuTou MM, was kinda afraid that would happen.Okay i edited it again. But im still not sure haha

Comment: Hahahahahas its okay I spent my last 8 hours testing don't mind spending another 8 hours :P This time the result turn out to be.. the whole column go empty LOL

Comment: Hey this work perfectly but now the problem go back, which is, how do I know the column to set the text to url link? *Sorry I went for dinner just now* ><

Comment: @MiloJuakMuTou Yes, that is an issue which i was expecting. I do not know a proper solution for that. you will need a workaround of some kind. If you know which columns are Sites before you databind, try to change those values like: "site" becomes "SITE:site" and than do an if(col.text starts with SITE:)<-- something like that.

Comment: ps: there is probably a way better solution for your last problem, so you could might want to google a bit around.

Comment: I think the best alternative solution I can think of will be getting the column index by finding the column name, then use back the column index in RowDataBound instead. But same problem.. I can't seem to get column index by the column name. Oh God LOL

Answer (score 1):

The second solution is a good way, but you do it wrong :

The RowDataBound event go through your DataSource and bind the GridView line by line. So you can't change this DataSource while it's being used.

You should do the same, go through your DataSource line by line (and modify the value you want to), but before the Databinding, when the DataSource is not used -> before the call *yourGridView.DataBind()*

===== EDIT ======

I offer you another solution :

You could add into your GridView, at the Column you want a HyperLink :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HLWebsite" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

and then, in the RowDataBound, you bind each HyperLink :

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   HyperLink HLWebsite = (HyperLink) e.Row.FindControl("HLWebsite");
   DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

   HLWebsite.NavigateURL = rowView["Website"].ToString(); 

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for suggesting a solution! But how can I get the specific column value row by row and modify it accordingly?

Comment: You have first to get the datable you want from the dataset, then you can go through rows, like foreach(DataRow row in yourTable.Rows).

Then for each row, you set the value as row["Website"] = "something" ;

Comment: Hi yes I had did something with the solution gave by @Koen but it display exactly like `<a href='http://example.com'>http://example.com</a>` instead of a link! :(

Comment: Hi thanks for alternative solution! But it seem like I can't add a `HyperLink` control inside my GridView, it only have `HyperLinkField` ><

Comment: It's weird usually you can ! Hmm I don't know HyperLinkField but i think you could do exactly the same as i quoted ! maybe properties have another name.

Answer (score 0):

End up I decided to use @Koen method but add in a regular expression to see which string to make it a hyperlink. How I doing it is that:

AFTER the GridView DataBind() I have this code

```
        if (chkWebsite.Checked == true)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gVRecruiterView.Rows)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                string value = cell.Text.ToString();
                if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$"))
                {
                    cell.Text = "<a href='" + value + "'>" + value + "</a>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case, at least for now, it solve my issues temporary :P Thanks a lots for peoples there suggesting solution!